# Anyone have an idea of what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python

the question is asking:
insert(obj, index, lst) # insert an element at specific index in a list and return updated

The input in the grader is

```
(('cat', 4, (18, 16, -28, 19, 41, -42, -49, 11, 18, 30))
```

I tried:

```
def insert(obj, index, lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] == index:
            obj == lst[i]
        return lst

print(insert("cat", "2", "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8,"))
```

I was expecting:

```
[18, 16, -28, 19, 'cat', 41, -42, -49, 11, 18, 30]
```

I’m not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. I know there are various ways to do this problem but ideally my prof would like for it to be solved either this way or in a similar way. Perhaps using .append. What I get in return is just my list which is "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8".

Comment: @KarolSzymczak it's not because someone is starting out, it's that the question does not have enough information to understand , the title is unhelpful for anyone searching for an answer, and while they gave a desired result, they didn't give any input that might lead to it. Why is the desired result `[The big cat ran away]` and what exactly is that? A string? A list of strings? This is why everyone always points people to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The formula for a question like this is not hard: 1. here's my input, 2. here's my expected output (as syntactically correct code), 3. here's what I've tried (passing the input into the code and showing the output) 4. here's my question (and any additional constraints). Without this people try to answer (as you see below) and it just leads to more questions and confusion, which wastes everyone's time.

Comment: sorry about the confusion, ill try to clean up my question and hopefully it helps everyone else understand it.

Comment: As edited, this does have a reproducible example, but there are at least **eight** things wrong with the code/question as given, so it's very hard to write anything meaningful in response.  Maybe try something even simpler, or reread the relevant part of whatever textbook first?

Answer (score 1):

You create `lstc` as an empty list, never update it, then return it. What result could there possibly be other than an empty list?

Within your conditional, you have `obj == lst[i]` which checks for equality, but doesn't *do* anything. If your goal is assignment, the operands are in the wrong order. You are testing `index == lst[i]`, but to compare indices, you likely wanted `index == i`.

If your goal is to modify `lst`, then `lstc` is completely extraneous.

```
def insert(obj, index, lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if index == i:
            lst[i] = obj
    return lst
```

Calling this:

```
>>> lst = "the big dog ran away".split()
>>> lst
['the', 'big', 'dog', 'ran', 'away']
>>> insert("cat", 2, lst)
['the', 'big', 'cat', 'ran', 'away']
>>> lst
['the', 'big', 'cat', 'ran', 'away']
```

Of course, this isn't really much different from:

```
try:
    lst[index] = obj
except:
    pass
```

If you don't to modify `lst`, you might use a list comprehension.

```
def insert(obj, index, lst):
    return [
        obj if i == index else x 
        for i, x in enumerate(lst)
    ]
```

Comment: thank you Chris, when I try your way, I still get "The big dog ran away" the goal is to replace dog with cat, but I am now noticing that I don't think I would be able to use indices. I think I would have to possibly use a different method perhaps count and .append?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to INSERT the object at position `index` in the list `lst`. You can simply do this by using the builtin insert function for lists. An example is linked [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-insert-an-object-in-a-list-at-a-given-position-in-Python#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20insert()%20function,inserted%20as%20arguments%20to%20it.).

You can write the following:

```
def insert(obj, index, lst): #index is an int
    lst.insert(index,obj)
    return lst
```

If you would like to REPLACE the object at position `index` with your `obj`. Then just write the following:

```
def insert(obj, index, lst): #index is an int
    lst[index] = obj
    return lst
```

I hope this helps.